# mod rewrite htaccess display link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issues with mod rewrite displaying the link in the browser correctly

I have always put links on my pages like this

```
 http://domain.com/contact-us.html
```

and then use this in my .htaccess file

```
 Options FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://domain.com/index.php?h=$1 [L]
```

I request the h variable on the index.php page to get and use the slug "contact-us"

```
 $h = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['h'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
 $h = preg_replace('/[^-a-z0-9_]/i','',$h);
```

This has always worked fine and will still show the domain.com/contact-us.html in the browser

I loaded a site on 1 and 1 and instead of seeing domain.com/contact-us.html I see domain.com?h=contact-us in the browser. Everything is working except it is not showing the link correctly

Answer (score 0):

Got it but for those it may help in the future. First clear your cache with each test

```
 Options FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?h=$1 [L]
```

Don't include the domain. In my case the website was up one level in the public_html folder so I thought I had to include the domain.

added

```
RewriteBase /
```

Works great, final code

```
 Options FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 Options FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?h=$1 [L]
```